# Why is Java labeled as a "secure" language?

Tags: java, security

I guess this is a general question, but I am going through introductory courses to java (SE/ME) and the study material claims that java is often used for "security purposes". It does not explain however what they mean by claiming that java incorporates good security.

Is it hacker proof? Does it produce highly stable software? What?

Security from my point of view (at the moment) is that it's in the hands of the developer writing the code, not the language itself?

Comment: Are you sure they're not saying "safe" rather than "secure?" Those are two entirely different things.

Comment: Can you include a quote from your study materials? Just saying 'secure' is pretty broad without more context.

Comment: The presentations related to the lectures brings up "security" to Javas strong points, the presenter then goes on listing javas usage as in banking system, stock market (nasdaq), smartcards and a couple more areas.

Comment: Java has very good(best I guess) Exception Handling mechanism. You can handle every assumed scenarios while developing. That makes it more secure.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

IMHO, that's a very misleading statement. In Java, you cannot access out-of-bound arrays, and you don't have pointers, and thus several security flaws like stack corruption or buffer overflow is impossible to exploit in Java. But Java is not inherently more secure than any other language; it's just there is less chance to make mistakes that can cause security flaws. In effect, this reduces security flaws, but it's totally misleading to say Java is secure.

Comment: Usually, when people say Java is "Secure" it is for exactly the reasons that you are stating - out of bound arrays and poor pointer arithmetic being two common security errors in C code.

Comment: It's more secure in the sense, that the chances are lower to compromise the system which is running the Java VM (the sandbox). What Lie Ryan ment is, that it doesn't make the application itself more secure. i.e. you can still have SQL injections, if you forge your SQL queries yourself and don't escape it correctly and similar "security" mistakes

Comment: so getting rid of what used to be **THE** most common cause  of security issues (buffer overrun/overflow) isn't being inherently more secure than, say, C? You are contradicting yourself in your own answer: *"Java is not inherently more secure than any other language"* (wrong) and *"In effect, this reduces security flaws"* (correct).  So what do you choose?  It is **NOT** because you don't guard against all security issues that you are not more secure than other languages.  Good luck escaping the VM Lie Ryan ;)

Comment: @Webinator, you're presuming an up-to-date JVM, which is **not** a safe presumption. Old JVMs are *easy* to escape. [This is an increasingly common problem.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mmpc/archive/2010/10/18/have-you-checked-the-java.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

There are two things that make Java "more secure" than other language in certain aspects:

- Automatic array bounds checking and the lack of manual memory management make certain classes of programming mistakes that often cause serious security holes (such as buffer overruns) impossible. Most other modern languages share this feature, but C and C++, which were dominant (and still are major) application development languages at the time Java first appeared, do not.
- The [Security Manager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/spec/security-spec.doc6.html) concept makes it relatively easy to run Java applications in a "sandbox" that prevents them from doing any harm to the system they are running on. This played an important part in promoting Java during its early days, since Applets were envisioned as a ubiquitous, safe way to have client-side web applications.

Comment: The security manager is broader than that, and still useful. You can assign different permissions to different codebases. This is very handy when you download some code.

Comment: I've heard wild rumors that it's not that hard to escape from the sandbox.

Comment: @Sami: there probably are Java versions where it's possible; JVMs have to get regular security updates like any other big, security-relevant software package. But there are definitely no generic sandbox-breaking methods.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of a tongue-in-cheek comment. But actually, it's almost trivial to escape from the sandbox in versions that are not the latest. There are normally no publicly known methods to escape from the sandbox of the latest version, but I wouldn't put too much trust on it.

Comment: +1 @Sami. See, e.g., [Java: A Gift to Exploit Pack Makers](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2010/10/java-a-gift-to-exploit-pack-makers/) "...attacks against Java vulnerabilities have fast emerged as the top moneymaker for authors of the best-selling “exploit kits,” commercial crimeware designed to be stitched into hacked or malicious sites and exploit a variety of Web-browser vulnerabilities."

Answer (score 8):

Java provides guarantees and tools for security, such as:

- No buffer-overflow exploits
- Byte-code verification
- Security permissions for different codebases
- Security-related APIs

For more details, see Oracle's ["Java Security Overview"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-security-overview1.htm).

Answer (score 5):

Because Java compiles as [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) which then runs inside a [Virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), it cannot access the computer it runs on like a natively compiled program can.

Comment: This is the same as .net code that compiles to IL and runs in the .net runtime.

Comment: Technically not true, since you can use JNI to access native calls to the system, and a java program can still wreak havoc on a system - deleting files, executing command-line arguments, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Several languages, most notably C and C++, have a class of bugs that can allow arbitary code to be executed when exploited - such bugs are quite common, and they're easy to make. These bugs are often some form of [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) .

Java, and many other languages/platforms eliminate that class of bugs(bar potential exploitable bugs in the VM itself), which many will claim makes it more secure.

Answer (score 3):

The general reason why Java is considered to be more secure than, say C, is because it handles memory management for you. In other languages, programmers allocate their own memory and often fail to do it correctly, causing buffer overflows, etc. Of course the Java VM could still contain the very same types of bugs, but it's well tested over time, unlike every user written program.

So in that respect, it is more secure. But you can still write insecure code, because no language could ever protect you from writing just plainly erroneous code.

Answer (score 3):

It is marketing)

Comment: Elegant answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler converts the Java code into byte code (.class file) and these byte codes are then run by Java Virtual Machine (JVM) . JVM is an interpreter which is installed in each client machine that is updated with latest security updates by internet . When this byte codes are executed , the JVM can take care of the security. So, java is said to be more secure than other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is basic question asked in some interview why java is secured its reason behind    this as java is secure because inside jvm a software is present whose name is security manager
   whose responsibility is that  handle all things, if something is happen wrong.so its control/preventing a system
2. Another thing is that it creates interface between source code and system(os),And no any permission of user to do something wrong.

Comment: What does this answer even mean?

Answer (score 1):

Also Generic types (or generics) bear a superficial resemblance to templates in C++, both in their syntax and in their expected use cases (such as container classes). But the similarity is only skin-deep -- generics in the Java language are implemented almost entirely in the compiler, which performs type checking and type inference, and then generates ordinary, non-generic bytecodes. This implementation technique, called erasure (where the compiler uses the generic type information to ensure type safety, but then erases it before generating the bytecode), has some surprising, and sometimes confusing, consequences. While generics are a big step forward for type safety in Java classes, learning to use generics will almost certainly provide some opportunity for head-scratching (and sometimes cursing) along the way.

Answer (score 1):

**

*> Why Java Is Secure Lanquage*

**

Reason: 
1. As java program runs inside its own virtual machine sandbox 
2. Data hiding in Java(OOPs) makes it one of the secure language.
Maybe some points are also there but cannot recall it right now.

3.No use of pointers preventing unauthorized access to memory block.

4.No access to the memory management

5. Access Control Functionality
6. Exception Handling
7. Use of final keyword
8. Package java.security provides the classes and interfaces for the security framework

Java security is enabled in each stage:
final keyword
secure class loading
jit security manager
byte code verification
automatic memory management
jsse 
java cryptographic extension
digital signature
jaas :java authentication and authorisation service

If you have learn this thing please like this